SAP Commerce Hybris Report Definition
Report Definition not returning any data
Trying to create a new Report Definition with the following query:
If I use this query in a FlexibleSearch in HAC it returns all the values I need, but when I created the Report Definition with this query it always returns empty... Can someone help please?
SELECT 
  {o.creationtime} AS "Data de Criação", 
  {o.code} AS "Número do Pedido", 
  {so.code} AS "Número da Ordem", 
  {o.totalPrice} AS "Valor do Pedido", 
  {o.deliverycost} AS "Total Frete", 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('|',{p.name}, ' QTD: ', {e.quantity}, ' R$', {e.baseprice}, '| ')) AS "Produtos"

FROM 
  {Order AS o
  JOIN SAPOrder AS so ON {so.order} = {o.pk}
  LEFT JOIN Consignment AS c ON {c.order} = {o.pk}
  JOIN OrderEntry AS e ON {e.order} = {o.pk}
  JOIN Product AS p ON {e.product} = {p.pk}}
WHERE 
  {so.transactionType} = 'YVEC'
  AND {o.creationtime} >= NOW() - INTERVAL '30' DAY
GROUP BY 
  {o.pk}, {o.creationtime}, {o.totalPrice}, {o.deliverycost}
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT {so.pk}) > 1
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT {c.pk}) != COUNT(DISTINCT {so.pk})

Example return:

Report Definition XML:
<itemtype code="RelatorioPedidosSplitYVEC" extends="Item" jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.util.ViewResultItem" generate="false" singleton="false" jaloonly="true" metatype="ViewType" autocreate="true">
    <custom-properties>
        <property name="query">
            <value>
                "`SELECT   {o.creationtime} AS \"creation\",   {o.code} AS \"code\",   {o.description} AS \"description\",   {o.totalPrice} AS \"total\",   {o.deliverycost} AS \"delivery\",   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(\' |\', {p.name}, \' R$\', {e.baseprice}, \' x \', {e.quantity}, \' unidades| \')) AS \"entries\",  COUNT(DISTINCT {so.pk}) AS \"sap\",  COUNT(DISTINCT {c.pk}) AS \"consignment\"FROM   {Order AS o  JOIN SAPOrder AS so ON {so.order} = {o.pk}  JOIN Consignment AS c ON {c.order} = {o.pk}  JOIN OrderEntry AS e ON {e.order} = {o.pk}  JOIN Product AS p ON {e.product} = {p.pk}}WHERE   {so.transactionType} = \'YVEC\'  AND {o.creationtime} &gt;= NOW() - INTERVAL \'30\' DAY GROUP BY   {o.pk}, {o.creationtime}, {o.totalPrice}, {o.deliverycost}HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT {so.pk}) &gt; 1  AND COUNT(DISTINCT {c.pk}) != COUNT(DISTINCT {so.pk})"
            </value>
        </property>
    </custom-properties>
    <attributes>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(1)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="consignment" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(7)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="creation" type="java.util.Date" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(0)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="delivery" type="java.lang.Float" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(4)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="description" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(2)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="entries" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(5)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="sap" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(6)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="false" autocreate="true" qualifier="total" type="java.lang.Float" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
            <persistence type="jalo" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="false" search="false" encrypted="false" optional="true" removable="true" initial="false" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="param">
                    <value>
                        Boolean.FALSE
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="position">
                    <value>
                        new Integer(3)
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>


You can enable flex query logging to check the query: https://gunce.mkysoft.com/log-sql-queries-which-are-created-with-flex/
Maybe you have restrictions which apply to your query.
